# How to change the focus of buttons displayed in prompt dialogs?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, catalina, macos

When a file is deleted through `Command + Option + Backspace` combination, the dialog like the image below is prompted to validate the operation with having two buttons which are `Cancel`, and `Delete` while the latter is focused by default. So, how can I change the focus to the other button through keyboard as I want to complete this operation without using trackpad?

[image]

p.s. OS: `macOS Catalina 10.15.1`

p.s. I have tried `Tab`, `Space`, `Option` but did not work for me.

Comment: I just want to mention that you could disable this confirmation question.

Comment: That would be better. How can I disable it?

Comment: My mistake, this dialog can't be disabled, but can be confirmed with Command+D.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `Tab` key behaviour from System Preferences:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to change the focus to other buttons. In the `Keyboard` preferences, there is a check such as `Use keyboard navigation to move focus forward and Shift Tab to move focus backward` as it is displayed below. This option is **unchecked by default**. Checking this option did the job.

[image]